# How do I enable user to invite (via email) other users to join in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, invite

I originally was using a plugin called acts_as_inviteable, but I can't get it to work on Rails 3.

It was pretty cool, it made it easy for an individual User of the site to click and invite a unique email to someone.  When someone clicked on the link they could register.

I want to extend that so that when they accept, they are now friends (using acts_as_network).

How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Comment: You can get `acts_as_inviteable` to work? Or you want to extend it do to something else?

Comment: Icouldn't get acts-asinvitable to work...looks like rails 2?  using devise_invitable...seems like its working